# Change Xml Attribute name with serialization at runtime

Tags: c#, xml, datacontract

I have a project in witch i have to crawl a given website and get some requested content specified by the user in a Xml file.

the configuration file is of this type. Here for the example i put two entries but it can have 1 or 2000.

```
<root>
    <item>
         <xpath>//meta[@name="description"]</xpath>
         <name>Description></name>
    </item>
    <item>
         <xpath>//meta[@http-equiv="Content-Language"]</xpath>
         <name>Language</name>
    </item>
</root>
```

the serialized database.xml is of this type :

```
   <itemCollection>
        <item>
            <Foo>somedata</foo>
            <bar>otherdata</bar>
            <RequestedData>
                  <SpecialData>Data asked by user</specialData>
                  <SpecialDatal>Other data asked by user</specialData>
            </RequestedData>
         </item>
    </itemCollection>
```

What i need (from the example config file) :

```
...
  <RequestedData>
    <Description>Some description</Description>
    <Language>Some language</Language>
  </RequestedData>
...
```

**I need the SpecialData attribute to be named with the Name value of the configuration file. In other words i need to dynamically and at runtime change the attribute name of a node**

Since i have to use a `XmlSerializer` this is quite an issue.

Configuration file is deserialized in an object with a `List<string>`.

```
public class RequestedData
{
    public string RequestedXpath { get; set; }
    public string RequestedName { get; set; }
}

public class ExtractDataOptions : List<RequestedData>
{
    public List<RequestedData> RequestedData;

    public ExtractDataOptions()
    {
    }
}
```

I have looked over the internet and i think the solution to my problem is to use `[DataContract]` or `DataCollection` but i have no idea where to begin with and i have trouble to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to try and map the XML to a class, then use [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not DataContractSerializer.

Alternatively, just parse the XML with [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pull the bits you need with LINQ to XML:

```
string config = @"

        <root>
            <item>
                <xpath>//meta[@name=""description""]</xpath>
                <name>Description</name>
            </item>
            <item>
                <xpath>//meta[@http-equiv=""Content-Language""]</xpath>
                <name>Language</name>
            </item>
        </root>                                             

        ";

var data = XDocument.Parse(config)
                    .Descendants("item")
                    .Select(x => new RequestedData()
                    {
                        RequestedXpath = (string)(x.Descendants("xpath").First()),
                        RequestedName  = (string)(x.Descendants("name").First())
                    });
```

Comment: Sorry i think i haven't been clear enough in my question. I have no problem to deserialize the config file. The issue here is to be abble to serialize a database file where i can dynamically, and at runtime change the attribute name value. For example make a <string>Something</string> node to a <MyValue>Something</MyValue>

Comment: If your "database file" is just an XML file sat on disk, then you need to write out all out again each time something changes. Maybe you could keep an XDocument in memory and alter that as needed, then just call XDocument.Save() to write it out again as required.

Comment: Sorry if i keep getting missunderstood, but the problem is not to save the file or anything with the file itself. The issue is how, using a XmlSerializer can i change the attribute of a node. Making the serializer understand that i don't want <Type>some info</Type> in the output file, but <XXX>Some info </XXX>. The "XXX" being something load from the name attribute of the config file.

Comment: Ah, finally with you! There's no way of doing this with static attributes that I know. You'll either have to implement IXmlSerializable in your class and write the nodes our manually, or again, use XDocument and add them manually.